# Nutch Fetch failed with protocol status: moved(12), lastModified=0: https://moorecompletedental.com/

Tags: nutch

when I do parsechecker url  https://moorecompletedental.com/
ouput of parsechecker is
2020-09-02 19:43:26,757 INFO conf.Configuration: found resource httpclient-auth.xml at file:/tmp/hadoop-unjar8666322013990061416/httpclient-auth.xml
Fetch failed with protocol status: moved(12), lastModified=0: https://moorecompletedental.com/
Redirect(s) not handled due to configuration.
Max Redirects to handle per config: 10
Number of Redirects handled: 0

I found some links to change property the http.redirect.max 10
But still I am getting same issue.
can anyone help me what changes I need to make so that I can crawl above websites.
I am new to nutch.

Answer (score 2):

The parsechecker tool provides a command-line flag `-followRedirects` to follow redirects:

```
$> bin/nutch parsechecker
Usage:
  ParserChecker [OPTIONS] <url>
    Fetch single URL and parse it
  ParserChecker [OPTIONS] -stdin
    Read URLs to be parsed from stdin
  ParserChecker [OPTIONS] -listen <port> [-keepClientCnxOpen]
    Listen on <port> for URLs to be parsed
Options:
  -D<property>=<value>  set/overwrite Nutch/Hadoop properties
                        (a generic Hadoop option to be passed
                         before other command-specific options)
  -normalize            normalize URLs
  -followRedirects      follow redirects when fetching URL
  -checkRobotsTxt       fail if the robots.txt disallows fetching
  -dumpText             also show the plain-text extracted by parsers
  -forceAs <mimeType>   force parsing as <mimeType>
  -md <key>=<value>     metadata added to CrawlDatum before parsing
```

The property `http.redirect.max` is then used to determine the number of recursively followed redirects. It is ignored when `-followRedirects` is absent.